Possibility of a formula for a given mathematical problem.
My question put informally asks whether there exists a possibility for a mathematical formula for a given problem or not. By ‘formula’, I mean to say about equations of different types that can be used as tools.
The formula usually means solving for the nth term in terms of the sequence of the natural numbers from $1$ to $n$. For example there exists a formula for the counting the nth AP or the nth term of the Fibonacci series.
For example does there exist one for the following sequence? Choose a natural number, write the number of times the previous term has appeared for the next term. For example, for $3$ the following happens: $3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, …$
I have tried to make an intuitive sense of for the periodicity of this sequence. But meanwhile I interested this way. Of course there exists the worst algorithm in terms of running time that could be implemented relatively easily, but I want the best algorithm which happens to be a mathematical formula that I am asking for.

This is called a "function." And if no such function exists you can always create your own and define it.
Your definition was not too clear but I understand what you are saying.

@qatest yeah I did not explain it clearly but kudos for understanding what I was trying to say. I want to find another function for this function that takes the nth as the input and outputs the term magically without doing it by definition.

The cardinality is the size of a set, and that's how you're using it here. You should use other word.

@SanskarAnand I think I see what you are saying. Although to do that might be impossible in some cases. For example the second number is always $1$. So the "term" can be anything if you are giving it the second term.

You can quite easily find this yourself, if you have the possibility to use Excel:
You create a title cell in "A1", you put $3$ in "A2" and the formula =COUNTIF(A$1:A2;A2) in "A3".
Then you start dragging down for some hundreds of cells, and after a short while, you'll see the following pattern appearing:
x
1
x
2
x
3
x+1
1
x+1
2
x+1
3
...

Once you've seen this, it becomes easy creating a general formula.
Oh, before I forget: if you put another number in "A2" (let's say $6$), you won't see the pattern x,1,x,2,x,3,x+1, ... but x,1,x,2,x,3,x,4,x,5,x,6,x+1, ....
Have fun!

Gotcha! So could I use excel for finding patterns by defining any function anyways?

@SanskarAnand: of course. Go ahead :-)

@SanskarAnand Sometimes Excel will help. Often it won't. It's just one of many tools in a mathematician's toolbox.

The answer to the general question you ask is "no". You won't always have a nice way to find the numbers in a sequence specified one term at a time.  But this particular sequence is A270572 at OEIS, and does have a formula:
>     A270572
>     a(1)=3; thereafter a(n) is the number of occurrences of 
>     a(n-1) in {a(1), ... , a(n-1)}.
> 

> For a(1)=3 the members of the sequence from a(12) onwards are of the
> form a(6*r+6)=1, a(6*r+7)=3+r, a(6*r+8)=2, a(6*r+9)=3+r, a(6*r+10)=3,
> a(6*r+11)=4+r, r>=1. For every integer a(1)>=1, from a(a(1)*a(1)+3)
> onwards, the members of the sequence are of the form a(n)=1,
> a(n+1)=a(1)+r, a(n+2)=2, a(n+3)=a(1)+r, ... , a(n+2*a(1)-2)=a(1),
> a(n+2*a(1)-1)=a(1)+r+1. n = a(1)*a(1)+2*a(1)*(r-1)+3, r>=1.


I am curious as to why. Why should it just make sense?

I think there is no general "why" for mathematical questions like this. If you calculate the next few terms for a while (I had to in order to find the OEIS reference) you can begin to see the pattern when you encounter a number for the first time. That leads to the formula. If you browse OEIS you will find many interesting sequences that don't have a formula.

I get what you are saying. Could it be possible to avail such numbers in a bunch for example, I mean a small set that contains the answer?

Your last comment is too general to make mathematical sense. The story is that some sequences have nice formulas and some don't and there's really no systematic way to tell. That's what makes mathematics interesting. It's figuring things out if you can, one at a time.

I get it and I do agree with you. But for sure there is a hype around such a question and it would be rewarding answers for such. Thanks for the help.
